XSLT: Number position inside apply-templates with condition
I need to print the position number when calling the template, but with have the condition. I.e. "position()" is not suitable.
<xsl:template match="property"  mode="table-group"> 
<xsl:variable name="property_id" select="@id" />    
  <xsl:if test="/shop//shop_group[@id=$group]/property_value[property_id = $property_id]/value != 0 and /shop//shop_group[@id=$group]/property_value[property_id = $property_id]/value != ''  "> 
    <tr> <td> 

 <b><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></b>     

    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="name"/> </td> <xsl:apply-templates select="/shop//shop_group[@id=$group]/property_value[property_id = $property_id]"  mode="table-group"/> </tr> 
 </xsl:if> 
  </xsl:template>

Please Help. It breaks my brain...
example xml:
<shop>
   <shop_groups_properties>
      <property id="01">
           <name>NameA</name>
      </property>
      <property id="02">
           <name>NameB</name>
      </property>
      <property id="03"> 
           <name>NameC</name>
      </property>
      <property id="04">
           <name>NameD</name>
      </property>
      <property id="05">
           <name>NameE</name>
      </property>
   </shop_groups_properties>
   <shop_group>
         <property_value>
           <property_id>01</property_id>
           <value>123</value>
         </property_value>
         <property_value>
           <property_id>02</property_id>
           <value>0</value>
         </property_value>
         <property_value>
           <property_id>03</property_id>
           <value></value>
         </property_value>
         <property_value>
           <property_id>04</property_id>
           <value>123</value>
         </property_value>
         <property_value>
           <property_id>05</property_id>
           <value>321</value>
         </property_value>
   </shop_group>
</shop>

I want get:
<tr><td>1 NameA</td><td>123</td></tr>
<tr><td>2 NameD</td><td>123</td></tr>
<tr><td>3 NameE</td><td>321</td></tr>

But If use "position()" I get wrong position:
<tr><td>1 NameA</td><td>123</td></tr>
<tr><td>4 NameD</td><td>123</td></tr>
<tr><td>5 NameE</td><td>321</td></tr>


Your question is incomprehensible. Please explain what exactly the problem is and provide a [mcve] showing an example of the input, an executable XSLT, and the expected output.

It sounds like you want to use a predicate instead of xsl:if. And defining a key would probably help to make the code shorter, if not more efficient.

Not enough. Your code refers to nodes that do not appear in your XML and to a variable that is not defined in the visible code. And you did not provide any explanation of the required logic.

Sorry.  I was wrong. I edited the code again.

I cannot help you if you're not listening.

Move the predicate to the xsl:apply-templates instruction that processes the  selected property elements:
<xsl:apply-templates select="//property[value != '' and value != 0]"/>

Within the xsl:template rule that is matched, position() will now have the right value.
(Note, the element names in your sample XSLT don't match the names in your sample XML, so this may need adjustment).

This option is not suitable. I changed the example to make it clearer.

I'm sorry, you haven't explained why my solution is not suitable. Perhaps you didn't explain the original problem clearly enough.

Your question is still missing an executable stylesheet and an explanation of what is it that the transformation is supposed to accomplish.
I suspect you are trying to do something like:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="propValue" match="property_value" use="property_id" />

<xsl:template match="/shop">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <xsl:for-each select="shop_groups_properties/property[key('propValue', @id)/value > 0]">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), ' ', name)"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="key('propValue', @id)/value"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>         
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

With the current version of the XML you have posted, this will return:
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>1 NameA</td>
            <td>123</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2 NameD</td>
            <td>123</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>3 NameE</td>
            <td>321</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>


You don't understand the point. I get the Names of the Property and the Values of this property, but only if the value is not =0 and is not empty. Therefore, the actual positions of the properties themselves do not match their position().
I don't need to change all my code. It is only necessary instead of
<xsl:value-of select="position()" />
come up with some kind of counter (like $i = i + 1) - which will output the real position.
although...I'm going to try to apply your code now

I tried to apply your code with @key@.
Groups can be nested within each other.
<xsl:key name="propValue" match=".//shop_group[@id=$group]/property_value" use="property_id" />

And i have error: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): Forbidden variable в файле /home/c/co09312/sitecltd.ru/public_html/modules/xsl/processor/xslt.php (строка 53)  XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error: file /home/c/co09312/sitecltd.ru/public_html/ line 23 element key в файле /home/c/co09312/sitecltd.ru/public_html/modules/xsl/processor/xslt.php (строка 53) XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): xsl:key : 'match' pattern compilation failed '//.//shop_group[@id=$group]/property_value' в файле /home/c/co09312/sitecltd.ru/public_html/modules/xsl/processor/xslt.php (строка 53)

I think the point that you don't understand is that XSLT has no mechanism for numbering nodes as they are output. The numbering you are getting is caused by your applying templates to all property elements, then outputting only #1, #4 and #5 of the currently selected node-set. The solution is to select only the property elements that meet your condition before processing them, as I have done or as was suggested by the other answer (which you have dismissed summarily as If you knew better).

Also, I test my answers before I post them and the code I have posted produces the exact answer I show, with no error.

Well, you need to come up with a mechanism for counting the template call through some other template, for example. This is the essence of my question!!!!!
There are no double slashes in your key - there are in mine (because
I need to go through all branches (shop_groups) - which cannot be applied inside key - error!

I won't be changing my answer. I suggest you spend more time studying XSLT,  perhaps things will become clearer.
